# Fast string matching in R

Tags: r, string

I'm attempting to do a word matching in a large data-set. I'm wondering if there is a way of speeding up the slowest operation in my workflow.

What I aim to do is to find the locations of the matches between a dictionary of words and a list of word vectors.

```
words <- c("cat", "dog", "snake", "cow")
scores <- c(1.5, 0.7, 3.5, 4.6)
dic <- data.frame(words, scores)

wordList <- list(c("jiraffe", "dog"), c("cat", "elephant"), c("snake", "cow"))
```

The fastest way I have found so far to do this is by doing this:

```
matches <- function(wordList) {
    subD <- which(dic$words %in% wordList)
}
```

My desired output is:

```
matches(wordList):
list(c(2), c(1), c(3, 4))
```

which I can later use to get the average score per wordList cell by doing

```
averageScore <- sapply(matches, function(x) {mean(dic[x, "scores"]})
```

Is there a faster way of doing the string matching than what I am doing in the function:

```
subD <- which(dic$words %in% wordList)
```

I have tried the dplyr way, thinking it might be faster, using first "filter" to get a subset of the "dic" and applying "colMeans" on it, but it seems to be twice as slow.

Also, running my matches function in a loop is just as slow as using "lapply" on it.

Am I missing something? Is there a way that is faster than both?

Comment: There are packages for fast matching, like `fastmatch`; and the `chmatch` function in the `data.table` package. Probably, these outperform anything we can whip up in a few lines of base R.

Comment: Is there an absolute requirement that you use the data structure of the list of word vectors you're matching against?  Your slowdown will come in the for loop structure employed with the call to sapply(). I would vectorize this operation by constructing a long-format data structure which you could then summarize easily with dplyr or the like.  I could draft an answer with this structure if you like.

Comment: To expand on Forrest's comment, you could start with a list (which is convenient for inputting the groups, and then convert to `mydf <- data.frame(w=unlist(wordList),g=rep(1:length(wordList),sapply(wordList,length)))` for faster analysis.

Comment: Alternately, `ww <- setNames(wordList,1:length(wordList)); stack(ww)`. Better to just assign sensible names to the groups in the list to begin with, in which case the first step is not necessary.

Comment: If your data is actually large (won't fit in RAM) then you should not be using R anyway. And if you are going to match many times then you should use a btree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
library(data.table)
nn <- lengths(wordList)  ## Or, for < R-3.2.0, `nn <- sapply(wordList, length)` 
dt <- data.table(grp=rep(seq_along(nn), times=nn), X = unlist(wordList), key="grp")
dt[,Score:=scores[chmatch(X,words)]]
dt[!is.na(Score), list(avgScore=mean(Score)), by="grp"]
#    grp avgScore
# 1:   1     0.70
# 2:   2     1.50
# 3:   3     4.05
```

Comment: Thank you Josh, this solution is elegant and much faster than what I had!